# ASP.net: ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock fires before jQuery is loaded

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

Interesting problem here from some inherited code I recently looked at. I'm trying to add a compression module to a project. It is loading all the JS and CSS files, combining them, minifying them, and compressing them. I've tried a number of solutions, but all of them have one fatal problem.

I have some javascript that is being loaded via Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock in the PreRender of the MasterPage. The compression module is loading as a Script Tag link in the MasterPage, but when I run the page... the code from the PreRender is lopped on top and is giving me a '$ is undefined' error, telling me jQuery isn't loaded yet.

Furthermore, I can't seem to get past the same problem when it comes to inline javascript on content pages.

Any ideas as to what is causing this? Enlighten me as I have no clue.

Comment: jQuery isn't designed to work before the DOM is fully loaded.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If have done this before with `RegisterStartupScript` (instead of `RegisterClientScriptBlock`)  and called the `$(document).ready(function()` from WITHIN that script.

Comment: Neat Solution. Had the same problem with ToolkitScriptManager, I ended up with the inserted script <script>$(document).blabla;</script> BEFORE the jquery source files <script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=x6wALODbMJK5e0eRC_p1L..." type="text/javascript"></script>.  I believe people use ScriptManager in a Master page to include jquery or other required scripts for their whole web site, maybe even using CombineScripts or the CompositeScript of ToolkitScriptManager. It seems VERY weird that RegisterClientScriptBlock insert its stuff BEFORE the ScriptReference of the ScriptManager.

Answer (score 0):

If the script tag link that eventually expands out to jquery is not in the head, but in the body of the page, then `$` will be undefined when the script block executes, unless it is included in the html before the opening `<form />` tag in the rendered html, which I understand is where `RegisterClientScriptBlock` spits out its script (just after that opening tag).

If this is not the case, and the joined/minified script is in the head, then I'd use a browser debugger such as Firebug or IE Dev Tools to verify that the jquery script is being correctly included in your combined script.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is late to the party, but try calling `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock` in your `OnPreRenderComplete` (rather than `OnPreRender`) handler. This inserts the code later in the page rendering process.

Answer (score -1):

All your jQuery code should be written inside the DOM-ready function:

```
$(function() {
    // your code here
});
```

indipendently from where you place it in the page, 'cause the jQuery() function isn't avalaible before.

Comment: $(document).ready(function () { ---> throws an error as $ is undefined.

Comment: Maybe you're trying to compress a minified version of jQuery? In this case I think it can generate some problems....

Comment: This answer is not quite correct. If the jQuery/$ function isn't available, `$(function(){});` won't work either. This function just tells jQuery to execute what's inside when the DOM is ready. But if jQuery isn't available yet, you'll get the error @jlrolin is talking about.

Comment: This does not address this issue. The problem is, as others have stated, the code that is added via RegisterClientScriptBlock (which uses jquery) is invoked before jquery is loaded.