# Calling jquery alert using ScriptManager in Asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a single line code that displays JS alert right now. I am trying to replace it with the jQuery alert so that I can theme it. Below is the code that I wrote for jQuery alert:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "onload", 
   "window.onload = function () {jAlert('This is a custom alert box', 'Alert Dialog');}", true);
```

This code used to be like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", 
    "alert('This is a custom alert box');", true);
```

The existing code works fine. But my code gives me an error saying,

`value of property jalert is null`

I am unsure, what I am missing here.

Comment: Is jquery.js loaded to the browser at the time the onload function fires?

Comment: I think so. Not sure how I can check if it is. Should I change the onload to something else?

Comment: You should check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760207/asp-net-clientscript-registerclientscriptblock-fires-before-jquery-is-loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running an external plugin to JQuery.

Make sure that on your page you have valid references to the `jquery` library and `jalert` plugin.

The `$.browser` property is considered obsolete and should not be used anymore. This is because there are a lot of browsers that misidentify about whom they are. IE12, for instance, identifies itself as a Mozilla browser.

You can find more information about the `$.browser` property [here.](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/)

If your version is JQuery 1.8 and under use this:

```
<!-- Dependencies -->
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- Core files -->
<script src="jquery.alerts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="jquery.alerts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

If your version is JQuery 1.9 and over, you'll need to reference the `jquery-migrate.js` file so that you can use the `$.browser` property:

```
<!-- Dependencies -->
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-migrate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- Core files -->
<script src="jquery.alerts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="jquery.alerts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Comment: Oh right. I know what I missed now. Stupid me. 

BTW, now the jquery.alerts.js file throws error saying `unable to get property msie` at this line `var pos = ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) <= 6 ) ? 'absolute' : 'fixed'; `.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? The property $.browser is not available with jQuery version 1.9 and above...

Comment: Really? Then how do I find the browser version in latest jQuery?

Comment: Anyway, I  switched to old jQuery file. Now the code seems to work, although alert does not show up as a popup, instead it shows up as a box behind the main section of the page. But that is a separate problem to figure out.

Comment: Open up the jquery.js file with notepad. The file will state its version in the header comments...

Comment: Thanks. I used 1.8 instead. Seems easier.